# Given a star's ra, dec how can I compute one pair of lat, long and time where the star would be at zenith?

Tags: star, coordinate

As the questions says, I have the celestial coordinates of a star(ra, dec). My trigonometry is not so great so I haven't managed to figure out a solution to this. I want to find a place (lat, long) and a time when the star will be right above the computed point?

I.e. star coordinates: 7h 23m 23.97s -13° 25' 2.64", where would be the point(lat, long) and time where the star would be right above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latitude is the easiest; it's the same as the star's declination: -13° 25' 2.64".

Longitude and time depend on each other. A star with right ascension 7h 23m 23.97s will be at the zenith point at 7h 23m 23.97s local [sidereal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time) (by definition). You need to convert sidereal time to local time (at a given day), e.g. with the script described [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20296/7472). On September 23rd (or whatever day the Fall equinox falls, thanks @MikeG) on the Greenwich meridian, this will happen at 7:23am UTC.

Comment: Sidereal and solar times coincide at the September equinox. At the March equinox they are 12 hours apart; e.g the Sun is at RA 0h but is on the meridian at noon as usual.

Comment: @MikeG ah, of course. Thanks, I've edited it in.